# Vancouver, Seattle & Hawaii from Australia on one ESTA?

Tags: usa, canada, esta, australian-citizens

I have a current ESTA for the US on my passport and travelling from Australia to

- Hawaii
- Vancouver
- Seward, Alaska
- Fairbanks
- Seattle
- train trip back to Vancouver
- bus to Lake Louise then back to Vancouver
- Hawaii
- homeward bound to Australia.

Will my current ESTA get us through the borders? I believe I will need one for Canada though.

Comment: How long will the total journey be (including the time spent in Canada)?

Comment: What is your nationality? It affects what paperwork you need to visit Canada.

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: Note that your proposed itinerary involves crossing the US-Canada border four times.  There's no problem with this *per se*, other than that it's a hassle each time.  Given this hassle, though, you might want to consider re-ordering the itinerary to reduce this.

Answer (score 5):

You will need an eTA if you're flying into Canada.

[Government of Canada website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?country=AU&result=2)

> **Fly to or transit through a Canadian airport:**
>
> You need to apply online for an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA).
>   You can apply with a valid passport, a credit or a debit card, and an
>   email address.
>
> **Drive or arrive by train, bus, or boat:**
>
> You don’t need a visa or eTA, but you do need to bring the [right
>   travel documents](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html).

[Apply for an eTA here,](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/apply.html) it costs $7CAD.

Your current ESTA will be fine for entering the USA by air or cruise ship on the Visa Waiver Program. You do not need an ESTA to cross into the USA at a land border but I have heard having one makes the process quicker.

VWP citizens do not need an ESTA to travel on the ferries between Vancouver and Victoria, BC and Washington state.  They are treated as a land border port.

**Please also note:** On this trip your time in Canada will class as time on your 90 days allowance under the visa waiver program so make sure your total trip is not more than 90 days.